# Changing a property to expression-bodied based on ReSharper leads to error?

Tags: c#, properties, resharper, expression-body

one of my properties looks like this:

```
public string Name
{
 get{ return _name; }
 set { _name = value; }
}
```

but ReSharper is advising me to change it to:

```
public string Name
{
 get => _name;
 set => _name = value;
}
```

if I refactor like that then compilation throws error
Is it not possible to have expression body in a Property ?

Comment: Waht error do you get?

Comment: C# 7? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members

Comment: apparently there's a version missmatch. this feature is only available with c# 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before c# 6 you couldn't use expression bodies in properties and had to write something like this.

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
}
```

In c# 6 you can create readonly experession bodies.

```
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
```

In c# 7 you got expression bodies for members like you showed.

```
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set => _name = value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want ReSharper not to adapt this behavior you can change it:

> Resharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Code Style

and change the following property:

> Code body > Properties, indexers and events from `Expression body` to `Accessors with block body`

If you just want to disable the suggestion change the notification state of the property mentioned above.